# node.js mqtt publish to mosquitto broker from callback

Tags: node.js, mosquitto

I'm unsure of how callbacks are 'queued' when using node.js which leads to a worry.

I have a tcp server that receives messages from the node mqtt client.  When a message arrives in the onMessage callback of the mqtt client, a method is called that sends it out to any connected TCP clients.  The server processes (at peak) about 150 messages per second of 50 - 300 bytes each.

Once in a while there are 'mystery' lockups.  The server is running but no messages are delivered to the clients.

It occurred to me that it's possible that a 'new' message arrives before the tcp server is finished servicing the clients with the 'last' message and I'm not certain whether this might confuse things.  I would expect that the function processing 'older' message handlers might get pushed onto a stack in favor of later arrivals - to be continued when all new messages have been serviced.

At the moment I'm not using any mutex's or other devices to prevent overlapping calls to the function that delivers the messages.  So my question is, should I trust node and the mqtt client to handle this level of messaging with possible overlapping arrivals or do I need to build in some kind of ***throttling, queueing or mutexing*** machinery?  If so, would the [kue module](http://learnboost.github.io/kue/) be a logical way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was not in my server but in the customers client.  The client was unable to keep up with the messaging volume (probably due to some blocking code on their end).

I found this by running the mqtt messages into a dequeue and throttling the number of messages sent to the client so that no less than 5 ms elapsed between messages.  Much to my surprise (and happily) the mystery message stopping problem went away after I did this.

The tricky part will be finding the minimum message gap that will allow the client to work reliably while making sure that the queue doesn't grow beyond a reasonable size.  As time allows I'll add some code to manage the max queue size by losing some messages until the customer can fix their client code.